# Facebook iOS SDK: No cancel button on login

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iPad app that uses Facebook's latest SDK (3.5.2). Once a user tries to login with Facebook or share something there's no way out of the login window. Safari is opened on FB login page and there's no way back to my app. If I close the window or try to manually go back to my app - it simply jumps to Safari again.
Screenshot:

[image]

I've read all the related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247222/ios-how-can-user-cancel-facebook-sign-in), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705450/how-to-cancel-facebook-login)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759160/facebooksdk-in-ios-does-not-show-close-button-and-not-able-to-close), but the answers there didn't help. I'm positive that FacebookSDKResources.bundle is part of my project and is referenced correctly.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add FacebookSDKResources.bundle from facebook SDK to your project.

- Go to Build Phases
- click +(plus) button in Copy Bundle Resources and add it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wrote in my question that _"I'm positive that FacebookSDKResources.bundle is part of my project and is referenced correctly"_

Comment: try it adding this way if you have added it with right click and add files. i was having the same problem.